# Finding the Transfer Function of a Multiplicative Distortion in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, filters, transfer-function, frequency-domain, distortion

[image]
I have the frequency response of two signals shown above. One is uncontaminated, and the other is the same signal contaminated by a multiplicative distortion with two poles and two zeros. I need to find/estimate the transfer function values of the contaminating filter in order to equalize the contamination. How do I accomplish this in MATLAB? Thanks.

Comment: Multiplicative in Frequency Domain or Time Domain? I guess in frequency but it is better to explicitly say it. As then it is not a multiplicative distortion but a Filter.

Comment: Can you share a CSV file with your measurements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically the transfer function is given by (Continuous time case):

$$ H \left( j \omega \right) = K \frac{ \left( j \omega - {q}_{1} \right) \left( j \omega - {q}_{2} \right) }{ \left( j \omega - {p}_{1} \right) \left( j \omega - {p}_{2} \right) } $$

Now, given your frequency data sampled an $ N $ points $ {\left\{ {\omega}_{i} \right\}}_{i = 1}^{N} $ we need to use the discrete-time form of the transfer function over the Z domain ([Z Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-transform)).
Hence the model becomes:

$$ H \left( z \right) {\mid}_{z = {e}^{j \omega}} = K \frac{ \left( z - {q}_{1} \right) \left( z - {q}_{2} \right) }{ \left( z - {p}_{1} \right) \left( z - {p}_{2} \right) }{\Bigg|}_{z = {e}^{j \omega}} = K \frac{ \left( {e}^{j \omega} - {q}_{1} \right) \left( {e}^{j \omega} - {q}_{2} \right) }{ \left( {e}^{j \omega} - {p}_{1} \right) \left( {e}^{j \omega} - {p}_{2} \right) } $$

you may set a system of $ N $ complex equations and use non linear solver to find the 5 parameters ($ K $, $ {q}_{1} $, $ {q}_{2} $, $ {p}_{1} $, $ {p}_{2} $)  you need.

In case the measurements are noisy you may use Least Squares.

**Remark**
The above solves the problem from the data of @[jmcd](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/users/54479/jmcd) in frequency domain. In practice, using the data domain one could use simpler [System Identification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_identification) (See [System Identification: An Overview](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4471-5058-9_100)) methods to get the equivalent ARMA model.
Regarding Frequency Domain based methods for System Identification have a look at Rik Pintelon - System Identification: A Frequency Domain Approach.

Comment: is this problem in continuous time or discrete time?  $s$ domain or $z$ domain?

Comment: You are right, I should have used a domain syntax to be clearer.

Comment: but Royi, the question is still there.  it's pretty clear to me that you are suggesting an answer (i think it's sorta a partial answer because no final solution is given, even with the *Least Squares*, but that's fine) that is in the continuous-time domain ($H(s)\Big|_{s=j\omega}$).  perhaps the transfer function the OP is looking for is in the discrete-time domain $H(z)\Big|_{z=e^{j\omega T}}$.  that will be a slightly different looking frequency response and the LS algorithm might come up with different poles and zeros (given the mapping $z=e^{sT}$).

Comment: may i modify your answer to cover both bases?

Comment: Yes, of course. I'd be honored.

Comment: Regarding the answer. If I had the measurements point in the plot (Say in CSV form) I'd add MATLAB code to solve it.